# Metric inside a sphere of uniform density?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, stars

Is an exact solution to Einstein's Field Equations known for the interior of a sphere of uniform density (to approximate a star or planet, for example?)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the exact solution is known. The general spherically symmetric metric is  $$g=-B(r)\mathrm{d}t^2+A(r)\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\Omega^2.$$

The solution for $A(r)$ is
$$A(r)=\left[1-\frac{2G\mathcal{M}(r)}{r}\right]^{-1},\quad\mathcal{M}(r)=\int^r \rho \,\mathrm{d}V=\int_0^r 4\pi r'^2\rho(r')\,\mathrm{d}r.$$
The solution for $B(r)$ is 
$$B(r)=\exp\left\{-\int_r^\infty \frac{2G}{r'^2}[\mathcal{M}(r')+4\pi r'^3 P(r')]A(r')\,\mathrm{d}r'\right\}.$$
In these equations $\rho$ is the density of the star and $P$ its pressure.

The derivation can be found in e.g.

S. Weinberg, *Gravitation and Cosmology* (1973), Sect. 11.1

R.M. Wald, *General Relativity* (1984), Sect. 6.2

N. Straumann, *General Relativity* (2013), Sect. 7.4

Comment: So taking $ r  >> 2GM (r) $ you get the Schwarzschild solution

Comment: Weinberg p. 302 has $2G/r^2$ not $2G/r'^2$. Who is right? OK, my copy is from 1972, so maybe it has a typo?