# How many tons of lead is needed to curve space 1 nanometer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, curvature, estimation

How many tons of lead is  needed to curve space 1 nanometer?

Comment: What does "curve space 1 nanometer" mean?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I mean the diameter of a circle around the mass which is really the length of the curve of the well in 2D. How should one word the question?

Comment: The problem is that measuring space curvature by Nano-meters is very unspecific.   Angle of curvature for a light ray passing just outside is more meaningful or, perhaps more accurate, the sum of 3 angles in a triangle.    If you want some much more detailed answers, look here:   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109731/how-to-measure-the-curvature-of-the-space-time   There are ways to measure distance sometimes but you need specifics, for example, Mercury appears to "jump" to the observer and a distance of that "Jump" can be measured, but that's a pretty specific scenario.

Comment: Oh, you mean, the circumference to radius ratio and enough gravity to add 1 nano-meter to the radius or remove 1 nano-meter from the circumference (2 different answers by the way), but due to gravity the radius to circumference ratio is no longer Pi.   The Math gets a little complicated for me.

Comment: The measurement I am after is the one that would run through a hole through the center of a lead ball. Then I wanted to know Would the curvature make the diameter out by 1 nanometer if you measured it with a rod?

Comment: @UserLTK. Yes that is what I was after. Then I wanted to know if anyone has ever tried to test it.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205950/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/174990/26076) and its references, you should be able to estimate this easily.

In the notation of that answer, if you measure out a length $\mathrm{d} R$ radially with a measuring rod of length $\mathrm{d} R$, the increase in radial co-ordinate $r$ is given by:

$$\mathrm{d} R = \frac{\mathrm{d} r}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2\,G\,\mathcal{M}(r)}{c^2\,r}}}$$

where $\mathcal{M}(r)$ is the mass contained inside a sphere defined by the radial co-ordinate $r$. In the case of a constant density $\rho$ sphere, the discrepancy between $r$ and a total $R$ measured by you by laying out measuring rods end to end is given by (I'm using the binomial theorem to approximate):

$$R\approx \int_0^r (1+\frac{4}{3\,c^2}\, G\, \pi\, \rho\, {r^\prime}^2)\,\mathrm{d}\,r^\prime$$

so that the discrepancy is estimated by:

$$R-r \approx \frac{4}{9\,c^2}\, G\, \pi\, \rho\, r^3 = \frac{1}{3}\,\frac{G\,M}{c^2}$$

or one sixth the Schwarzschild radius for a mass $M$, meaning you will need quite a few elephants, or tonnes of lead, to see the discrepancy of the magnitude you seek.

You can also glean the same formula from [Feynman's elementary introduction to GR in chapter 42 of the second volume of the lectures (equation 42.3)](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_42.html). Incidentally, the discrepancy works out to about 1.5mm for the Earth at its surface.